# How can i get this format through function

Tags: php

I am getting date in this format

```
$date = '2019-01-02';
```

but i want a function to change this format into Month day , year format like ( `may 2 ,2019`)

```
$date = "May 7 , 2019" // i want date to be like in this format
```

How can i get this through function please help me related this i an newbe in php thanx in advance .

i need function to get this because i wanted to use this format in multiple places

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Do this way,

```
$date = '2019-01-02';
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($date));
```

**Output:**

```
January 2, 2019
```

Comment: i want to remove 0 from the date starting

Comment: Jan 2,2019 it should be like ... here january come in full charecter i need only starting 3

Comment: @Sonam You've gotten a lot of help here in this answer already - all you need to do is change the format. See a full list at http://php.net/date - I suggest you read the flagged duplicate under your question for a deeper understanding.